# Raster function in r returns empty raster during conversion from an spatial data frame

Tags: r, interpolation, geospatial, raster

I am running the following code to convert an an inverse distance weighted interpolation of nitrate values from a spatial data Frame. The problem is I have an empty raster when I convert it to raster as shown below. The `idw` function appears to work well and returns two values `vra1.predict` which has values in it and `var1.var` that is empty

[image]

Is there something I am doing wrong with the raster function that it casting the raster to be empty or is am I doing something wrong in the ids function or potentially an issue with my inputs?

my code is below

```
idw<-idw(formula = results ~ 1, locations = spdf, newdata = grd, idp = 1.0)

r       <- raster(idw$var1.pred)
```

The raster comes out empty

Comment: Hi @jdiales1! Please dont upload your data as an image for [these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/12109788), but instead edit your question include code to recreate example data. If you need tips on how to do that, you can find some [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Good luck!